# Is there a touch-friendly casino gambling (poker, roulette, slot machine) application that interfaces with coin acceptors

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Does anyone have experience with gambling games (roulette, poker and so on) on Ubuntu?

I would like to setup a touchscreen kiosk in my home with Ubuntu...
Anything that works with coin and cash acceptors, reports payouts, lets the administrator set payout rates and so on

Any experiences/hints?
I am interested in full statistics / pay tweakings / cash flow analysis..

Comment: Please make your question a bit more specific (for example, "Is there a touch-friendly roulette application that interfaces with coin acceptors"). This way you'll get better answers.

Comment: @Daniel I don't think Pitto wants to just play some poker, rather build a Kiosk computer with a touch screen, like a video slot machine. This sort of software works with coin and cash acceptors, reports payouts, lets the administrator set payout rates and so on. It'd be very interesting to know if there's anything like that (possibly free software) for Ubuntu.

Comment: You absolutely got the point, Stefano! I'm editing the question :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what kind of coin acceptor you're using, but you can see something related to payment computing on these sites:

[KMyMoney](http://kmymoney2.sourceforge.net/index-home.html)

[Quasar Point-of-Sale](http://www.linuxcanada.com/pos.shtml)

[Future Net](http://www.futurenet.com.au/)

You can search on google if the payment system you have already had been used successfully on ubuntu.